Questions on formatting mathematical papers
I would like your opinions and advice on the following questions:

Is it acceptable to number important equations in a paper even if they are not directly referenced in the text? This could make it easier to reference them in later papers, I think.
Is it common or recommended to include a "Contents" block in a 24-page paper?
Why do the majority of mathematical papers (about 99%) not include a "Conclusion" section? Is there a specific norm or preference for the structure of mathematical papers that explains this trend?



The conclusion of a mathematical paper is often the statement of a result (theorem, etc...). One typically likes to read the theorem before its proof, and this is usually done in the introduction.



Yes. 2. It is common, and also common to omit. The question is whether it's useful, and this depends on the paper. Also one has to wonder whether to include subsection numbers in the table of contents.



If we want to announce future research related to the results of the article, should we typically include this in the conclusion, or can it also be placed in the introduction?


Usually it fits well in the introduction (however, I'm skeptical that a mathematical paper is a good place to make announcements).

@Yc This seems a good answer; please post it as an answer, not as comments though.

In N. David Mermin's book, Boojums All The Way Through – Communicating Science In a Prosaic Age, he reprints the essay, "What's wrong with these equations," from Found Phys. 14, 1 (1984). He gives three rules. Rule 1 (Fisher's Rule) ... Number All Displayed Equations. Rule 2 (Good Samaritan Rule) ... When Referring to an Equation Identify It by a Phrase as Well as a Number. Rule 3 (Math is Prose Rule) ... End A Displayed Equation with a Punctuation Mark.
